# How to get this form to submit only when it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

Probably an idiotic question but I find this really tricky:

I am trying to make a form submit only when it specifically should.
The script below executes every time I submit any other form in my page.

How can I make it not execute, unless it is called for?

```
$('#nurturing_pop_up_form').validate({

rules: {
        emailaddress: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        board_meeting: {
            required: {
                depends: function () {
                    return $('input[name=in_12_months]').is(':checked')==false && $('input[name=in_6_months]').is(':checked')==false
                }
            }
        }

},

submitHandler: function(form) {

    var url_remind = 'http://example.com';
    var data_remind = $('#nurturing_pop_up_form').serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url_remind,
      data: data_remind,
      success: function(){
        $('.nurturing_pop_up').fadeOut(); 
        }       
    });
}
});
```

Should I add something like this?

```
    $('#nurturing_pop_up_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#nurturing_pop_up_form').validate({
    rules: {
    //the rest like above
```

Help is very very appreciated!

Comment: You're showing us nothing that demonstrates what you're describing.  Construct a *complete* demo that includes the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make a form submit only when it specifically should.

This process is handled *automatically* by jQuery Validate.  You should **not** be doing anything special to force this.

> The script below executes every time I submit any other form in my page.

The script "below", `.validate({...})`, is simply the plugin's initialization routine.  Within the code you've shown, you are only initializing ONE form with `id="nurturing_pop_up_form"`.  Other forms on the page would be completely unaffected.  Perhaps you have invalid HTML, additional instances of `.validate()`, other submit handlers, or some erroneous code you have not shown us.

> How can I make it not execute, unless it is called for?

I think your question is based on an erroneous assumption of what's happening. `.validate()` is only supposed to be called ONCE on page load (DOM ready handler) to *initialize* the plugin on your form.  The plugin then *automatically* captures the click, validates the data, and handles the submit.

> Should I add something like this?

```
$('#nurturing_pop_up_form').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#nurturing_pop_up_form').validate({...
```

**Absolutely not.**   You should **never** put `.validate()` within a `.submit()` handler for the same form.  It's completely unnecessary, delays the plugin's initialization, and interferes with the built-in submit handler.

Nothing you've shown can explain how/why other forms would be affected.